# Kotlin. Interface as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, interface

I am storing static data in an Enum. There can be many of them, but they have the same structure, which is specified by a special interface, to simplify work with all of them. I used similar logic in Swift and it works, but Kotlin does not allow me to use such logic.

```
interface DataElement {
    val code: UInt
    val name: String
}

enum class DataEnum1: DataElement {

    Apple {
        override val code: UInt
            get() = 1u
    },

    Orange {
        override val code: UInt
            get() = 2u
    },

    Watermelon {
        override val code: UInt
            get() = 3u
    }
}

enum class DataEnum2: DataElement {

    Blueberry {
        override val code: UInt
            get() = 4u
    },

    Strawberry {
        override val code: UInt
            get() = 5u
    },

    Blackberry {
        override val code: UInt
            get() = 6u
    }
}
```

Here's the problem

```
fun someFun() {
  val array = DataEnum1.values()
  anotherFun(array) // TYPE MISMATCH
  //Required:
  //Array<PeripheralDataElement>
  //Found:
  //Array<DataEnum1>
}
    
fun anotherFun(items: Array<DataElement>) {
     // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are invariant in Kotlin, meaning that you cannot directly pass a `Array<SubClass>` to a function accepting `Array<SuperClass>`. However, you could define your function like this to make it accept a covariant array:

```
fun anotherFun(items: Array<out DataElement>) {
    // ...
}
```

Now your function also accepts `Array<SubClass>`.

Side note:
This automatically works with lists because `List` is defined as covariant in it's type argument on the interface level, like `interface List<out T>`.

Comment: To clarify: the reason this is prohibited is that the function could be _adding_ any object that implements `DataElement` to the array, and that could be a `DataEnum2` even if the array's concrete type is `Array<DataEnum1>`.

Comment: Initially, I wanted to use List. But the values () method returns an array

Comment: @TimYumalin You could also convert it to a list using `DataEnum1.values().toList()`

Comment: @marstran In this case it makes more sense to use `asList()` instead of `toList()`. `toList()` copies the data, `asList()` just wraps the array.